# Issues with grabbing values out of a table

Tags: mysqli

Ive written the following pieces of code, and supposedly every user has an ID and an username.

```
  function fetchIDByUsername($username)
  {
    define('DB_SERVER','NOPE');
    define('DB_USERNAME','NOPE');
    define('DB_PASSWORD','NOPE');
    define('DB_NAME','NOPE');
    /*Attempt to connect!*/
    $link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
    $query = mysqli_query($link,'SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`="'.$username.'"');
    $response = mysqli_fetch_object($query);
    return $response;
  }
```

And to call this function I use

```
echo fetchIDByUsername("masecla22");
```

And it should say 1 becuase that is my id, but it spits out this error

```
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, i had to add ->id; after the return statement.